# Multiple Firestore queries, single promise / callback

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I understand that Firestore doesn’t support logical OR for queries.
My idea is to create multiple queries and merge the results at the client.
I am developing a news app and I am trying to fetch all articles that contain my users’ interests tags (ex. technology, music etc) 
An average user has 20 tags so I will be making 20 different requests.

Does anyone has experience with chaining multiple requests and returning a unique promise when all results arrive.?

I am using the js sdk

My data structure:

articles (collection)

```
-article (document)
--id: 10
--time: 1502144665
--title: "test title"
--text: "test text"
--tags(obj) 
---technology: 1502144665,
---politics: 1502144665,
---sports: 1502144665
```

So I will need to create multiple db requests like the following.

```
user.tags = ["technology","politics","sports","architecture","business"];

for (var i = 0; i < user.tags.length; i++) {
  db.collection('articles').where(user.tags[i], '>', 0).orderBy(user.tags[i]))
    .get()
    .then(() => {
        // ... push to article array
  });)
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to create a promise / callback when every request finishes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can save each of the database access Promises in an array, then use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get a Promise that resolves when each of the database accesses is complete.  (This code is not tested, it may contain some syntax errors, but it demonstrates the idea.)

```
user.tags = ["technology","politics","sports","architecture","business"];

var dbPromises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < user.tags.length; i++) {
  dbPromises.push(
      db.collection('articles')
        .where(user.tags[i], '>', 0)
        .orderBy(user.tags[i])
        .get()
  );
}

Promise.all(dbPromises)
    .then(() => {
        // ... push to article array
};
```

Comment: How is this possible in Java/Android ?

Answer (score 11):

Here is an ES6 friendly version that uses some functional paradigms to reduce complexity

```
let articles = db.collection('articles')

user.tags = [
  'technology',
  'politics',
  'sports',
  'architecture',
  'business'
]

// map each tag to a firestore query
let queries = users.tags.map(tag => {
  return articles.where(tag, '>', 0).orderBy(tag).get()
})



/*
  Use Promise.all to aggregate the results
  and wait for all of them to complete
 */

Promise.all(queries).then((querySnapshots) => {

  /*
    querySnapshots is an Array[QuerySnapshot]
    reduce all our querySnapshots to only their DocumentReferences
   */

  return querySnapshots.map(qs => qs.docs)
                       .reduce((acc, docs) => [...acc, ...docs])

}).then((matchingArticleRefs) => {

  /*
    matchingArticleRefs is now an Array[DocumentReferences] from firestore
    if no documents matched the queries above it will be an empty array
   */

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my goal with the following code...

```
window.firebaseData = [];
window.firebaseQueue = [];
var testTags = ["technology","design","entertainment","world","fashion","food","architecture","science","movies","graphics","gaming","photography","finance"];

for (var i = 0; i < testTags.length; i++) {
  window.firebaseQueue.push(testTags[i]);
  var tagString = "tags."+testTags[i];
  window.db.collection('data').where(tagString, '>', 0).orderBy(tagString).limit(100)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      updateQueue(testTags[i],true);
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        var data = doc.data();
        window.firebaseData.push(data);
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      updateQueue(testTags[i],false);
  });
}


function updateQueue(tag, success){
  if(success){
    arrayRemove(window.firebaseQueue, tag);
    if(window.firebaseQueue.length < 1){
      console.log("All finished");
    }
  }else{
    console.log("Failed: " + tag);
  }
}
```