# How to use multiple where clause in Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

I want to list a sort of data from firestore. each document contains a "Status" field. I need to pull out 3 different types of status from the list. how do I do that in dart for my flutter project?

the following code, it doesn't work for me.

```
getStream() {
  var snapshots = firestore.collection("booking")
  .where("userId", isEqualTo: uid)
  .where("status", isEqualTo: "confirmed")
  .where("status", isEqualTo: "unconfirmed")
  .where("status", isEqualTo: "unconfirmed quotation")
  .snapshots();
  return snapshots;
}
```

Comment: Firestore doesn't support logical OR queries.  You can instead make one query for each condition you want to match, and merge the results.

Comment: you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807243/8992034), hope it helps