# Firestore multiple queries on two fields with observable

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am Using Angular and Firestore.

I would like to execute a multiple query to Firestore database on two fields. It's now possible with the `WHERE` statement that you can combine.
My idea is to combine the values, then send request to the database. For example I want to get back all the Post where the city is Los Angeles, San Francisco, New York and the Rated Stars are 5, 4.

So I have to make a query of 6 possible combinations:

```
Where city = Los Angeles
Where Stars = 5
```

...Then next query

```
Where city = Los Angeles
Where stars = 4
```

...Then next query

```
Where city = San Francisco
Where Stars = 5
```

...Then next query

```
Where city = San Francisco
Where Stars = 4
```

etc..

I know how to do it with a `For` statement for one field and one value like you can see in the code below, but I don't know how to combine them (group the combinations in multiple queries), then to wait for all to execute (with observables or subject) to group them in an Array of result. I found two answers on Stack, but no one really help me to take the good decision.

This one but it's only on one field, and not observables
[Multiple Firestore queries, single promise / callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552876/multiple-firestore-queries-single-promise-callback)

This other one 
[Firestore multiple range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658651/firestore-multiple-range-query)
Who give the good idea to "perform filtering on one field in the query, and one the other field in your client-side code."
This solution is good if u have few results, but if you have a lot, it can slow the process, taking back data that we don't need.

```
export class AnnoncesListComponent implements OnInit {

  queryParams: { departement:string, secteurAct:string };
  subscriptionChange:Subscription;
  annoncesSubscription:Subscription;
  departementGet: any;
  secteurActGet: any;
  annonceQuery: Annonce[];
  isFetchingData:boolean = false;

  constructor( 
    private activeRoute : ActivatedRoute,
    private annnonceService: AnnoncesService 
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
//Get QUERYPARAMS FROM THE URL
   this.departementGet = decodeURIComponent(this.activeRoute.snapshot.queryParams['departement']);
   this.secteurActGet =  decodeURIComponent(this.activeRoute.snapshot.queryParams['secteurActivite']);
   this.departementGet = this.departementGet.split('_B2-');
   this.secteurActGet = this.secteurActGet.split('_B2-');

//FOR - TO QUERIES ALL THE DATA NEEDED - FIRST QUERY
   for (var i = 0; i < this.secteurActGet.length; i++) {
    this.annoncesSubscription = this.annnonceService.getAnnonces('secteurActivite', this.secteurActGet[i])
    .subscribe( responseData => {
      this.isFetchingData = false
        this.annonceQuery = responseData.map(item => {
          return {
            id : item.payload.doc.id,
            secteurAct : item.payload.doc.get('secteurActivite'),
            departement : item.payload.doc.get('departement'),
            region : item.payload.doc.get('region'),
            description : item.payload.doc.get('description'),
            infosClefs : item.payload.doc.get('name'),
          } as Annonce;
        })
        console.log(this.annonceQuery);
    });

//FOR - TO QUERIES ALL THE DATA NEEDED - SECOND QUERY
   for (var i = 0; i < this.departementGet.length; i++) {
    this.annoncesSubscription = this.annnonceService.getAnnonces('secteurActivite', this.departementGet[i])
    .subscribe( responseData => {
      this.isFetchingData = false
        this.annonceQuery = responseData.map(item => {
          return {
            id : item.payload.doc.id,
            secteurAct : item.payload.doc.get('secteurActivite'),
            departement : item.payload.doc.get('departement'),
            region : item.payload.doc.get('region'),
            description : item.payload.doc.get('description'),
            infosClefs : item.payload.doc.get('name'),
          } as Annonce;
        })
        console.log(this.annonceQuery);
    });
};
```

My result is two separated Datas without combinations, and with the creation of an observable on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe is a good approach to use rxjs/forkJoin for handling multiple parallel requests.

[ForkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) accepts an array of observables as its first argument and returns an observable that emits once all of its passed in observables have completed.

I have refactor your code to something easier to read and that takes advantage of forkJoin to handle departaments and secteurs in parallel so then outputs an array of each resulting data.

If the amount of data you are working on is quite big i would even suggest taking a look into [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) so its possible to split cpu intensive operations in multiple threads and avoid blocking the main thread.

```
    // map array of departments into an array of Observables
    const departmentsRequests = this.departementGet.map((departement) => {
        return this.annnonceService.getAnnonces('departement', departement);
    });

    const secteurActiviteRequests = this.secteurActGet.map((secteur) => {
        return this.annnonceService.getAnnonces('secteurActivite', secteur);
    });

    // forkJoin takes all Observables and emits once to its subscription
    this.annoncesSubscription = forkJoin([
        forkJoin(departmentsRequests),
        forkJoin(secteurActiviteRequests),
    ]).subscribe(([departaments, secteurs]) => {
        this.isFetchingData = false;

        // all data has been loaded in parallel from firestore, handle it here
    });
```

Comment: Thanks u very much for you re precious help. I'll do this to join the observables, then sort the results with the combinations of the two values (department and Secteurs). I wanted to do this sort (combination) in the queries, but this solution look more easy. I'll come back with the solution and post if its working or not, for the result i need.

Comment: I am not able to get the data after forkJoin. I tried to add an operator to get the payload, but it looks like its not working after forkJoin, when its working on other subscribe without grouping the observables. 
I found this course on RXJS: https://ultimatecourses.com/learn/rxjs-basics and i am going to take it, because it really need a solid understanding of its way of working, before to be able to use it correctly. I dont understand how to get back the payload after the forkJoin operator...

Comment: It is a great course! I already took all of these courses from Todd Motto and is fully recommended.

The payload (resulting data) should be available at the callback passed in to the subscribe method. Its possble that one of the observables (requests) is throwing an error and then this callback is never called. Why? the subscribe method accepts 3 parameters, all of them callbacks:
1. success
2. error
3. complete

If one of the observables fail it would execute the error callback. Maybe that's the reason you are not receiving the data. As always take a look into the console for errors.

Comment: Hi and thanks. Yes i am doing his course right now and its great. Ill finish this course, then be able to modify the code and come back with a solution for this post. Observable are complexe at the begining, and without good foundations its impossible to understand how they clearly work.
For the callbacks if i take them one by one its working, its when i use both in ForkJoin that the result not coming back.

Answer (score 0):

The function in the service to get back the Data is this one :

```
 getAnnonces(champ, valeur){
        return this.firestore.collection('annonce', ref => ref.where(champ, '==', valeur)).snapshotChanges();
      }
```

I had you 're code but when i try to output the result:

```
 // forkJoin takes all Observables and emits once to its subscription
      this.annoncesSubscription = forkJoin([
          forkJoin(departmentsRequests),
          forkJoin(secteurActiviteRequests),
      ]).subscribe(([departements, secteurs]) => {
          this.isFetchingData = false;
          // all data has been loaded in parallel from firestore, handle it here
          console.log(departements);
      });
```

There is no result. I try with .get() instead of .snapshotChanges(), but he give me back a [QuerySnapshot]